# Why does "user_path" cause a routing error in views done by "render" but not by "redirect_to"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The "link_to" below works fine when the view is generated by a "redirect_to", but causes a unknown routing error when the view is generated by "render".  It seems the URL helper doesn't propagate during renders?

```
link_to "user link", user_path(@user)
```

Comment: A view is never generated by a `redirect_to` and always generated by a `render`. You need to provide more information and code to clarify what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `@user`. That might be the issue.